# Angularjs version issues: Default select of a disabled option

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, version, ng-options

Why is that in angularjs 1.4.x, doing a default select of a disabled option does not work, but works well in angularjs 1.5.x?

For example, the following code works well with angularjs 1.5.5 (selects **white** by default which is **disabled**):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-select-production</title>


  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-app="selectExample">
  <script>
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.myColor = {name:'white', shade:'light'}; // red
    $scope.colors = [
      {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'white', shade:'light', notAnOption: true},
      {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'blue', shade:'dark', notAnOption: true},
      {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
    ];
  }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">


  <label>Color filtered by shade, with some disabled:
    <select ng-model="myColor.name" validate-on="dirty" required-message="'This field is required'" ng-disabled="false" ng-required = "true"
          ng-options="color.name as color.name group by color.shade disable when color.notAnOption for color in colors | filter:{'shade':'light'}:true">
    </select>
  </label><br/>




  <hr/>
  Currently selected: {{ {selected_color:myColor} }}
  <div style="border:solid 1px black; height:20px"
       ng-style="{'background-color':myColor.name}">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But changing the version to, for example, 1.4.7 in the `script` tag in the above example does not select **white** by default
See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/UAOFj5MEow3xEWH0ZLyz?p=preview

How do I get the behavior in 1.4.x that works fine in 1.5.x?

Comment: Bug fix.  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/832eba5fc952312e6b99127123e6e75bdf729006.  It is unlikely that you would be able to patch this in to 1.4.x due to the number of changes that `ngOptions` goes through in each angular revision.  However, it seems to only be a few changes to the actual code (and the removal of a test case), so it might be possible to create your own derivative of the 1.4.x code with these few changes.

Comment: +1 for the pointing out the correct bugfix for this issue. But still I am not so sure, if this will be a good idea